# Deleted whole /etc/apt catalogue Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS minimal headless server

Tags: apt, server, updates

Today i deleted whole /etc/apt directory (don't ask me how/why xD)
I already managed to reinstall apt with

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_2.4.5_amd64.deb
```

also created sources.list and added standard repositories to it, now it looks like this:

```
deb https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse

deb https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
```

The problem is that when I do

```
sudo apt update
```

I get:

> Err:2 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                 Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (185.125.190.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (185.125.190.36). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (91.189.91.38). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (91.189.91.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
> Err:3 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                         Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
> Err:4 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                        Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
> Err:5 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                       Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:443 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)                                                                                                                             Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                         W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
> **E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.**
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

Is there any way to solve this ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you include the listing of `ls -a /etc/apt`? Maybe you're missing some keyrings etc.

Comment: After this kind of big mess I always recommend reinstall. You could be spending weeks trying to fix this and it is never stable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the source reference to use `http` instead of `https` for the first 4 repositories:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then, you need the Ubuntu APT keyrings as well:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-keyring/ubuntu-keyring_2021.03.26_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./ubuntu-keyring_2021.03.26_all.deb
```

Hopefully this will now allow you to connect to the repositories.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was extremely helpful! Problem solved

Comment: That's good to hear - cheers! 